# Where to ask for a specific brand of food

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm looking for a brand of cookies from my childhood. On which Stack Exchange site should I ask?

Comment: Possibly [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/), but, as always, check their help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com) does have the tag [food-identification](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-identification) but the excerpt says:

> When you can provide photos or description of a food you've seen or heard of but don't know its English name.

So be sure you have a good enough description of your memory, preferably with a picture of the cookie.

You might find the discussion on this topic on their Meta useful: [Is asking to identify a food from a picture on-topic?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1172/is-asking-to-identify-a-food-from-a-picture-on-topic/1174#1174) as well as their [What is on topic page](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)